# Increase counter if a value exists

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

In my database, I am searching for a specific value. If that value does not exist, it should simply be added, but if it exists, a counter should be added next to it.

So for instance, if the value *Hello World* already exists, the added value should be *Hello World 1*, the next one should be *Hello World 2* and so on...

This is what I have tried:

```java
int id = newQuoteRepository.findByTitle(data.getTitle()).size();
System.out.println(id);
if (id > 0) {
    data.setTitle(data.getTitle() + id);
}
```

Well, basically it works but it is not really what I want. So if a value is `bar`, it will add `bar1`. And next time, it will add `bar1` again, because it is searching for `bar` and so the added value, which was `bar1`, will be ignored.

So this is what I have: bar, bar1, bar1, bar1 ...

And this is how it should be: bar, bar1, bar2, bar3 ...

What could be a solution for this issue?

Comment: This seems like a problem with your model. If "title" really has to be unique, mangling it is probably the wrong approach; perhaps there's a type missing from your model that relates to (references) the quote. More likely, the title is just some information in a record that doesn't need to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to add a `counter` column to your table and whenever you need to show your title, concatenate the title with this counter.

e.g.

```java
int id = newQuoteRepository.findByTitle(data.getTitle()).size();

if (id > 0) {
    data.setCounter(data.getCounter() + 1);
    // persist it
}

// Show title:
System.out.println(data.getTitle() + " " + data.getCounter());
```

There are several advantages to this approach.

- You work with numbers directly
- No need to do some `String` magic to achieve what you want
- Cleaner

Comment: You are right. It is much cleaner that way. Thank you! Besides, I have replaced `data.setCounter(data.getCounter() + 1);` with `data.setCounter(id);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findByTitleLike` instead of `findByTitle` for your task.It will find titles  match with the given regex.

Comment: So what if my table includes the values `bar` and `bar & foo`? In that case, both of them will be selected.

Comment: If that the case you have to use findByTitleLike

Comment: Check whether %bar[0-9]* work for you as regex